# LogStash specific fields as index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm trying to sync data between mongo and Elasticsearch with Logstash.

I am using json files as input and single outputs to different elasticsearch indexes. I am still seeing the index generated by elastic search as random UUID. Instead I want the status field to be indexed.

Here is my config:

```
input{
  file{
    path => ["/Users/vicky/Downloads/ESpoc/data/staging.json"]
    type => "json"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
output { 
    elasticsearch { 
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "staging"
    document_id => "%{[status]}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a sample line of `staging.json`?

Comment: Try removing brackets from `document_id => "%{status}"`